# Email is not sending from server

Tags: php, laravel

I have `live` laravel application, and I'm working on `password reset` functionality.

Having the following `routes`

```
Route::get('passwords/reset/{token?}','Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');

Route::post('passwords/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');

Route::post('passwords/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.reset');
```

Clicking on `Forgot My Password` links directs me to the following `form`

```
<form action="{{ url('passwords/email') }}" method = 'post'>

<input type="email" name = 'email' class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter Your Email Here" style = 'text-align:center'>
  <button type='submit'>Send Link to Email to Reset Password</button>

</form>
```

From this `form` I want the user to put his/her `email` and we shoot of a reset link with `token` to that `email Id`.

For that I have the ForgotPasswordController

```
 public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
 {
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

// We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
// to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
// need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
$response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
    $request->only('email')
);

if ($response === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
    return back()->with('status', trans($response));
}

// If an error was returned by the password broker, we will get this message
// translated so we can notify a user of the problem. We'll redirect back
// to where the users came from so they can attempt this process again.
return back()->withErrors(
    ['email' => trans($response)]
);
```

}

I want to send `Email` to that `email Id` with the `token` but that is not sending.

Following is my `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=myEmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

In my `config/mail.php` I have this

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myEmail@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'myName'),
],
```

**Note**

I have allowed `less secure apps` for my `gmail` account, still I'm getting no email, and I'm making these changes to a live site.

This is what the `storage/logs` shows

> local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'alle_voertuigen_nl_carseller.password_resets' doesn't exist (SQL: delete from `password_resets` where `email` = myEmail@gmail.com) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 42S02):

Although I have `password_resets` table that I created manually, and not through `php artisan migrate` because I'm making changes to live site, and that I don't know how to use `command line` for deployed project

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Open your `storage/logs` and find the latest log by date, you should see more info about your email and why it failed, and you will probably find your answer there. If you can't figure it out by yourself, past the log of the emails into your question,

Answer (score 0):

You should use 587 port if you using tls, not 25

Comment: It seems OK but i need to see you php mail log.
I guess it contains some info about itself.

Comment: _i need to see you php mail log_ , what do you mean by that ? @LanceHunter

Comment: try to catch error by something like that:
try{
    Mail::send('emails.configuration_test', array(), function($email)use($request){
        $email->to($request->test_address)->subject('Configuration Test');
    });
}
catch(\Exception $e){
    // HERE is error
}

Comment: You can add any test controller, just for testing your mail system. But before you do this, try one more thing. Clear cache by: php artisan config:cache
then try to send email like you did it before

Comment: okay, one side not that I'm on making these changes to the live files,how can I run these commands lik `clear cache`, please let me know because I'm searching for this for too muc time @LanceHunter

Comment: Please mention any `controller` specifically so that I can add these `lines` of codes, because this will send `email` how to add this to any `test` controller ?
Please suggest inform of answer ! @LanceHunter

Comment: Please have a look at the updated post , I added what I have in `storage/logs` @LanceHunter

Answer (score 0):

Change your .env file with the below details

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Don't use your original password..create an App Password in your google account.
After saving the changes in the .env file run `php artisan config:cache` command.

Comment: why would I need that `App Password` can you please explain ? @jitesh jose

Comment: To add more security to your google account by not directly entering the password,use app password.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Modify your mail.php file as bellow i mentioned [statically] and one more thing, remove mail parameters from the .env file. 
Do not forgot to run "php aritsan cache:clear" & "php artisan config:cache" command.
This will help you in local server and live server as well.**

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
|            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => 'smtp',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => 587,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => 'Your gmail address',
    'name' => 'Your Name',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => 'tls',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => 'Your gmail address',

'password' => 'Your Gmail password',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Markdown Mail Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
| theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
| of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
|
*/

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
],
```

];